# How can I debug a GWT project in Netbeans

Tags: debugging, gwt, netbeans

I am developing a GWT project with Netbeans. When I debug it I always get the screen saying "Development Mode requires the GWT Developer Plugin". The problem is that my version of firefox is too recent to run that plugin. So what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Update to GWT 2.7, DevMode no longer requires a browser plugin (uses so-called "super dev mode" instead; where you debug in the browser rather than the IDE)

Comment: thomas:can't we debug the code in IDE rather than Browser?

Comment: If you IDE (and browser) supports remote debugging and sourcemaps, then yes it's possible (but limited compared to debugging a Java app). IntelliJ IDEA supports it natively (but using a browser extension IIRC), and you can get it in Eclipse using the [SDBG plugin](https://sdbg.github.io); can't tell for NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply i will try this(+1)

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation for using the [GWT Hosted Mode debugging](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html#compile-debug) in Netbeans, but you should be better able to use the newer [GWT Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html). To be able to set breakpoints in Netbeans though, you'd need to properly configure the source map support in Netbeans to map between the compiled JavaScript and the source Java files. I wasn't able to find an obvious reference for doing that with Netbeans.

The fun thing was that [gwtproject.org](http://gwtproject.org) made the sourcemaps part of the released site, and there was a tutorial to using them against their site to step you through how to setup your IDE... But again I didn't find that for Netbeans... Here's an example java source that's linked from gwtproject.org's JavaScript sourcemaps:
http://www.gwtproject.org/src/com/google/gwt/site/webapp/client/GWTProjectEntryPoint.java